# how can I reinstall ubuntu while using it by formating whole hard disk?

Tags: 14.04

I want to reinstall the Ubuntu and install it again by formating my whole hard drive please help

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

When you will come to **Installation Type** step, simply select **Erase disk and reinstall Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple steps you can follow through to re-install ubuntu:

1. Create a bootable CD/DVD or USB-Drive with the version of Ubuntu you want to install: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
2. Boot from the CD/DVD or USB-Drive into the Ubuntu you want to install. Then you have 2 options.

   - either you run the installation and use the "replace other OS" option during Installation or "something else" to change your partions during installation process.
   - or you open a terminal and run `sudo gparted` - here you can change the harddrive partitions as you like, and then install ubuntu after changing these settings.

You might aswell check for duplicates of this question, as linked in the comments above.